# Cannot run my App on a device disconnected from Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, xcode12

With the last version of Xcode (12.0), I do not succeed to run my App on my device without usb cable.
When connected, the app is installed and works well, but when I remove the cable the App closes and I cannot reopen it...

Then, I have an alert on Xcode saying "Lost connection to the debugger..."
I tried to modify the Runner configuration settings with Releaser and Debug, but same results.

For info: I am using Flutter sdk.
Please help..

Comment: Hey I just found this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657#issuecomment-688478590